# Simultaneous wsfed and hrd authentication in an application - Thinktecture Identity Server

Tags: identity, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model

I need to support both authentication methods in an application - WS Federation (wsfed) and Home realm  discovery (hrd). I am having installed and customized Thinktecture identity server, but I am stack with achieving the above scenario. I am not sure what should be the configuration in `<system.identityModel.services> <federationConfiguration>` section.

Can I have two `<wsFederation...>` elements there and how the system would know which protocol to use?

Also is it possible to combine to method in a single page on the identity server side?

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both, then configure the server for hrd and then as a RP you can configure IdentityServer as a RP to its own hrd endpoint. There's an issue in the github issue tracker with more info (you'll have to search there).

Comment: Thank you, Brock for this reply. I tried this, but for any reason it didn't worked. Anyway I will check the issues in the github for details.

Comment: It works like a charm. I am pasting here and url to the issue in the github, just in case that someone else need it: https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/484